# FileSystem vs FileContext for file operations in hdfs/localFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm used to work with [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to do file operations in hdfs(and local FS for tests). Recently I faced a need of atomic renaming and though FileSystem has an [overloaded method](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#rename-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.Rename...-) with such capabilities:

```java
protected void rename(Path src, Path dst, org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.Rename... options)
```

it's protected and deprecated. I tried to find a way to solve this and found [FileContext](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileContext.html) it has the same method and it works fine. Every example I could find on the Internet uses `FileSystem`. So I wonder why there are two classes to do the same thing and is it ok to use `FileContext` instead in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#rename-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.Rename...-) has a note that for the version of `FileSystem.rename` with three parameters:

`This method is deprecated since it is a temporary method added to support the transition from FileSystem to FileContext for user applications.`

To your question of "is it ok to use FileContext instead in my case", it sounds like yes.